# Paypal IPN Simulator is not triggering my IPN handler

Tags: joomla, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I'm trying to troubleshoot a problem with a Joomla component I brought as the developers aren't helping at all.

When I set for an order through the website and pay for it through PayPal, it returns to the website but the IPN handler - ipntest() - hasn't been triggered.  ipntest() should send me an email when triggered.  I have used the IPN Simulator to try and trigger ipntest() and it says that its been sent successfully but the ipntest() doesn't trigger.

If I view the function directly in my browser (e.g. http://example.com/index.php?option=com_mycomponent&task=orderprocessor.ipntest), it works fine and sends the email.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: You may be interested in this article about [how to test PayPal IPN](https://www.angelleye.com/test-paypal-ipn/).  If you follow those steps you should be able to find your issue because you can troubleshoot within a browser, which makes it a lot easier.

Comment: Thanks. It ended up being a problem with the component as the ipn handler function was private so PayPal couldn't reach it. I have notified the component developers as they didn't realise so they must not have tested it.